# SharePoint 2010 List Permissions / Group Permission levels

Tags: 2010, list, permissions, groups, custom-permission-level

If a SharePoint list has unique permissions.

Would the owners of the subsite or site collection with Full Control be still able to access the List?

If a SharePoint Group has both "Read" and "Limited Access" level of permissions,
or a  group has "Contribute" and "Limited Access" given to it.

Which permissions would the group have?

The Contribute level gives the group access to edit the items and delete the items, whereas limited access prevents it. But if a group has been given both the access levels....... What access would the group members have?

Answer (score 2):

If a List has unique permissions, and a group has Full Control for a site but not Full Control *on that list* then the group would not be able to access that list.

With regards to mixed permissions, Limited Access would override Contribute or Read, because Limited Access by purpose can also deny access to *specific* resources. This does not mean however, that it would negate their contribute permissions. Right now, I have a group in my site that has contribute and limited access. The limited access is due to them not being allowed to access particular document libraries. So unless limited access is denying specific resources, contribute would override it.

EDIT:

[image: SharePoint Group]

This SharePoint group has general permissions Full Control, Contribute, and Limited Access.
[image: SharePoint Group]

In this Document library, It's set up so this very same group that has Full Control only has Read in this specific instance.